# Arranging html elements in a specific layout

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and I'm practicing some layouts in which I'm trying to get something like below:

[image]

But I'm having difficulties achieving the "Surname" layout which is beside the "Title" field and the "Surname" text box is aligned with the GivenName longer text box at the end.

I attempted the following:

[image]

But I couldn't seem to get surname to appear beside "Title" and ensuring the end of its text box is aligned with the given name textbox at the end.

Would appreciate some help on this.

HTML and CSS code:

```css
.small_field {
    width: 80px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.long_field {
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.entity {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>testform</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "test2.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "entity">
        <label >Title</label>
        <input type = "text" id = "title" disabled class = "small_field">
    </div>
    <div class = "entity">
        <label >Surname</label>
        <input type = "text" id = "surname" disabled class = "small_field">
    </div>
    <div class = "entity">
        <label id = "">GivenName</label>
        <input type = "text" id = "givenname" disabled class = "long_field">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried float: left; ?

Comment: You want the boxes to be the same width? Or what?

Comment: @user13806962 sorry if you’re confused but I’m just trying to achieve the layout like the first image. Perhaps let’s keep it as simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

Flex could be used here :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form,
.entity {
  display: flex;
}

form {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.entity.full {
  min-width: 90%;
}

.entity,
.entity>* {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0
}

.entity>.long_field {
  flex: 3.35;
}

input {
  border: green solid;
}

label {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="entity">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" disabled class="small_field">
  </div>
  <div class="entity">
    <label>Surname</label>
    <input type="text" id="surname" disabled class="small_field">
  </div>
  <div class="entity full">
    <label id="">GivenName</label>
    <input type="text" id="givenname" disabled class="long_field">
  </div>
</form>
```

see that guide to go further : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

grid is also a possibility , here is another guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ .

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form {
  padding: 10px;
}

form,
.entity {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.entity {
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.entity.full {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}

label {
  width: 8em;
  text-align: right;
}

input {
  border: solid green;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="entity">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" disabled class="small_field">
  </div>
  <div class="entity">
    <label>Surname</label>
    <input type="text" id="surname" disabled class="small_field">
  </div>
  <div class="entity full">
    <label id="">GivenName</label>
    <input type="text" id="givenname" disabled class="long_field">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: yes an example would be great. Technically I too would avoid using methods such as position:absolute and so because I do read that it is not a good way of positioning elements as it might break easily when resizing or etc.

Comment: @Maxxx okay, added a grid example .I also dislike absolute for dispatching a layout. that is not made for this. IMHO . ;)

Answer (score -2):

There are lots of ways to place elements beside each other. A simple way is to put a `div` around the title and surname fields and give it `display: flex`.

Answer (score -5):

I don't quite understand what ur trying to achieve, but if ur trying to change the position of `Surname` u can add `position : absolute;` in css and then with `left :`   and `top :`  u can put it anywhere